# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)

Tags: flutter-plugin, flutter-packages, url-launcher

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)

I am getting this error while using any plugin. The above error is from using url_launcher. I also get similar error using image_picker.

> Here's my pubspec.yml dependency list

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+1
  http: ^0.13.3
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
```

> Here's the response from flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/tarekfaysal/fvm/versions/stable
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (3 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /users/tarekfaysal/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
• CocoaPods version 1.11.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Mi A2 (mobile) • fff60a • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
• Chrome (web)   • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.61

• No issues found!
```

I tried "flutter clean" and uninstalling the app from local device and did "flutter run", still this error persists.

> Please help!

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) shows, you need to add this in your androidManifest.xml file (for android):

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

For IOS, add this in your Info.plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>https</string>
  <string>http</string>
</array>
```

*Note: You need to stop and restart your application to see the change (in your emulator)*.

Comment: god bless you my brother,you saved my day!